# WPF Richtextbox images and resize adorners

Tags: c#, wpf

Good morning,
I have a richtextbox which allows me to insert an image via right click context menu. This functionality works, and the image is inserted into the richtextbox with no issues (adorner shows).

[Working adorner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLfKB.png)

The issue I have is that when I export the .rtf to xml I loose all the adorners and clicking on the image doesn't allow me to resize it.

[Not working adorner post export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSIP6.png)

The export code that appears to break the adorners is:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentXamlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "DocumentXaml",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(RichTextBoxHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
            {
                BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
                PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) =>
                {
                    var richTextBox = (RichTextBox)obj;

                    // Parse the XAML to a document (or use XamlReader.Parse())
                    var xaml = GetDocumentXaml(richTextBox);
                    var doc = new FlowDocument();
                    var range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);

                    range.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xaml)),
                          DataFormats.Rtf);

                    // Set the document (*this breaks the adorners*)
                    richTextBox.Document = doc;

                    // When the document changes update the source
                    range.Changed += (obj2, e2) =>
                    {
                        if (richTextBox.Document == doc)
                        {
                            MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream();
                            range.Save(buffer, DataFormats.Xaml);
                            SetDocumentXaml(richTextBox,
                                Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.ToArray()));
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
```

I wanted to know how I can re-set the adorners on existing images, when I click on them, or not loose the adorners during the conversion to xml when the above code is called.

Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Tithras

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, it was during the conversion of the text from rtf to xaml and then back again during the binding, this basically killed the adorners.